# How to read config variable in Phoenix / Elixir?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'd like to set the title of my app in `my/config/config.exs` file:

```
config :my, My.Endpoint,
  url: [host: "localhost"],
  root: Path.dirname(__DIR__),
  secret_key_base: "secret",
  title: "My App"
```

How can I read `title` later to use it in template? Something like:

```
<div>
  Title of my app is <%= ??? %>
</div>
```

I tried `conn.title` and it says there's no such key. But, when I try `conn.secret_key_base` it works. Why?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You may use `Application.get_env(:my, :title)`

Comment: You must have the dev.exs, prod.exs and test.exs files to get the current environment configurations.

Comment: This answer is incorrect, at least on my system. [tiagohngl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35754803/118220) gives the proper incantation.

Comment: app parameter is `:my`, and key is My.Endpoint. So this answer is incorrect. The one by @tiago-herique-engel should be checked

Answer (score 78):

The [get_env](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/Application.html#get_env/3) function is part of the Application module from the Elixir/Erlang core.

This function returns the value for a specific key in the app's environment.
Considering your configuration, you would access the `title` property this way:

```
Application.get_env(:my, My.Endpoint)[:title]
```

The third parameter is for passing a default value when the config key doesn't exist.

Answer (score 20):

Let's say in dev.ex file you have a config variables

```
config :app_name, AppName.Endpoint,
  api_prefix: "api/v2",
  api_host: "http://0.0.0.0",
  api_port: "3000"
```

You can fetch all three config variables

```
Application.get_env(:app_name, AppName.Endpoint)[:api_prefix]
Application.get_env(:app_name, AppName.Endpoint)[:api_host]
Application.get_env(:app_name, AppName.Endpoint)[:api_port]
```

Answer (score 6):

To have clear separation between my custom configuration and configuration for phoenix and other modules I used:

```
config :ace, :config,
  root: Path.dirname(__DIR__),
  title: "Ace"
```

And then you retrieve the value using a get_env call like:

```
iex> Application.get_env(:ace, :config)[:title]
"Ace"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you look under the hood how the config is just a function that add config values to a keyword list and later you can access them in your app

`config/2` takes a key and maps it to keyword_list,
`config/3` takes a key and adds key with keyword_list as value.

Since you are using `config/3` it namesapces your config under My.Endpoint this would work `Application.get_env(:my, My.Endpoint, :title)`

Comment: `config/2` adds multiple key-value pairs in one call, while `config/3` add only one pair. There's always a as first app parameter.

Application.get_env always fetches one value for the given key and in the given application. The third parameter specifies a default value, in case the the app or key are missing.

Comment: Using `Application.get_env(:my, My.Endpoint, :title)` is just plain wrong.  My.Endpoint always has values, and :title isn't an appropriate default (clarifying febeling's comment)